# What species is this fly?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, diptera

I am looking for an ID of this fly at genus or preferably species level.
Location: The Netherlands.
Size: approx. 7-8mm 
Habitat: indoors, attic.
Timing: usually appears late winter, early spring
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is a *Pollenia sp*
https://forum.waarneming.nl/smf/index.php?topic=447650.0.

One of the common species from this genus, *Pollenia rudis*, is often found overwintering in groups in attics and is therefore known as the [cluster fly or attic fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_fly).